# How to customize the Template of the ToolTipService.ToolTip?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

**Silverlight** provides `ToolTipService.ToolTip` for basic applications.

However, I want to customize the `Template` of the `ToolTip` by doing something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello"  >
  <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
     <TextBlock Text="I can help you." />  <!--replace this with my template-->
  </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

I want the `Content` or `Style` property of the `ToolTip` to be able to be set dynamically from a `DataContext`.

Something to this effect:

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockWithToolTip}" />
```

Answer (score 11):

You're not going to be able to use the Style property in the exact way you want.  The `ToolTipService.ToolTip` property is an **Attached Property**.  You can't use a Style resource to assign a value to an attached property.

However you can use a Style resource to style a `ToolTip` element.  Hence your `TextBlock` could look like this:-

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty}">
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource TipHelp}" />
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

Now in your containers Resources you can have a style such as this:-

```
<Style x:Key="TipHelp" TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeOtherProperty}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter> 
</Style>
```

You can now customise the contents of the `ControlTemplate` to you desired ToolTip appearance wiring it up with appropriate Binding objects.

Answer (score 1):

Someone had the same issue and made quite a nice project in CodePlex.

With this, you can even bind the `ToolTip` text (which was a showstopper for me because I use localization through binding).

Here's the link: [link text](http://tooltipservice.codeplex.com/)

Works really great.

Comment: I know this is a late comment, but could you possibly update your answer to show how to use this CodePlex ToolTip to solve the OP's issue?